# Using ruby and nokogiri to parsing HTML using HTML comments as markers

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, comments, nokogiri

How could I use ruby to extract information from a table consisting of these rows? Is it possible to detect the comments using nokogiri?

```
<!-- Begin Topic Entry 4134 --> 
    <tr> 
        <td align="center" class="row2"><image src='style_images/ip.boardpr/f_norm.gif' border='0'  alt='New Posts' /></td> 
        <td align="center" width="3%" class="row1">&nbsp;</td> 
        <td class="row2"> 
            <table class='ipbtable' cellspacing="0"> 
                <tr> 

<td valign="middle"><alink href='http://www.xxx.com/index.php?showtopic=4134&amp;view=getnewpost'><image src='style_images/ip.boardpr/newpost.gif' border='0'  alt='Goto last unread' title='Goto last unread' hspace=2></a></td> 

                    <td width="100%"> 
                    <div style='float:right'></div> 
                    <div> <alink href="http://www.xxx.com/index.php?showtopic=4134&amp;hl=">EXTRACT LINK 1</a>  </div> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 
            <span class="desc">EXTRACT DESCRIPTION</span> 
        </td> 
        <td class="row2" width="15%"><span class="forumdesc"><alink href="http://www.xxx.com/index.php?showforum=19" title="Living">EXTRACT LINK 2</a></span></td> 
        <td align="center" class="row1" width='10%'><alink href='http://www.xxx.com/index.php?showuser=1642'>Mr P</a></td> 
        <td align="center" class="row2"><alink href="javascript:who_posted(4134);">1</a></td> 
        <td align="center" class="row1">46</td> 
        <td class="row1"><span class="desc">Today, 12:04 AM<br /><alink href="http://www.xxx.com/index.php?showtopic=4134&amp;view=getlastpost">Last post by:</a> <b><alink href='http://www.xxx.com/index.php?showuser=1649'>underft</a></b></span></td> 
    </tr> 
<!-- End Topic Entry 4134 -->
-->
```

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example?  Specific input and output?

Comment: @Michael: There is sample text, and it appears in preview but not in the question. Fixing it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a Nokogiri [SAX Parser](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html). This is done faster than it might seem at first sight. You get events for Elements, Attributes and Comments.

Within your parser, your should rememeber the state, like @currently_interested = true to know which parts to rememeber and which not.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `xpath` instead:

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><body><!-- Begin Topic Entry 4134 --></body></html>") 
html_doc.xpath('//comment()')
```

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted solution, since it's the most straightforward.